# track def excute in django

Tags: python, django, logging, tracking

I want by default see all def run without any customizing code

example

```
[date] settings.py
[date] url.py
[date] /apps/views/views.py run index def 
[date] ...
```

is there any middle were or something do this job?

Comment: settings and url not def ... only as exampel

Comment: i saw this http://packages.python.org/lettuce/tutorial/simple.html but i didn't want add some thing like decorator for each def

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough one. First of all, logging *every* function (proper term for “def”) would probably a bad idea and unnecessary. You might want to look at the python [trace module](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html).

If you are just trying to debug what's happening in a Django app and want to do so with a middleware, look no further than the awesome [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/).

If you want to log Django activity (which is probably what you are asking for), the [django-logging-middleware](https://github.com/djangrrl/django-logging-middleware) is perfect for this case.

Comment: django-logging-middleware was awesome